# How to save create a table of file paths?

Tags: matlab, cell

I'm trying to perform object detection with rcnn on a custom dataset based on the [matlab stopsign detection tutorial](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/trainrcnnobjectdetector.html). First I need to create a table of **file paths** and the **bounding box of objects**. So I want to create a table in which the first column is filled with the full path of images. How can I do this?
I already tried to create a cell of full paths, but it just works with the file names when I try this:

```
imgPath = {files.name}
```

But when I try this:

```
imgPath = {strcat(files.folder, '\', files.name)}
```

it just creates a 1x1 cell of the first image file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creation of cell worked with this:

```
for id = 1:length(files)
    imgPath{id,1} = fullfile(dir,files(id).name);
end
```

But I still don't know how to create the table.